# Join to previous weekday skipping weekends

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, coalesce

I am trying to join data based on the weekday prior to the [Date_Pulled] column. For instance, on Mondays[Date_Pulled] I want to pull Fridays[date] data and Tuesdays[date] I want to pull Monday's[Date_pulled] data.

I do this to avoid nulls, since we do not generate rates on weekends.

Heres what I've tried:

```
select a.lane, a.them, b.us a.date_pulled, b.date
from table a
left join table2 b on a.lane = b.lane    
    AND A.[DATE_PULLED] = COALESCE(DATEADD(DAY,+1,B.[DATE]),(DATEADD(DAY,+3,B.[DATE])))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not certain, but it sounds like a Calendar table or Date Dimension would be helpful here.  Here's an example.  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Comment: Are you pulling the data from same or different table ? If it is same table, you can use `LAG()` since you said there will not data in weekend

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
from a join
     b
     on (b.date = dateadd(day, -1, a.date) and datename(weekday, a.date) <> 'Monday') or
        (b.date = dateadd(day, -3, a.date) and datename(weekday, a.date) = 'Monday')
```

Note that this assumes English internationalization settings for the weekday name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` expression to work out how many days back to look e.g.

```
select a.lane, a.them, b.us a.date_pulled, b.[date]
from a
inner join b on a.lane = b.lane
    and b.[date] = dateadd(day, case when datepart(weekday, a.date_pulled) = 2 /*Monday*/ then -3 else -1 end, a.date_pulled)
```

Note: assumes [`DATEFIRST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) set to 7, Sunday. Adjust to suit your system.